# numpy comparisons between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to compare rows of two different dataframes (short subset as example):

```
data:

                                       Chr  Strd    start        end
Read name               
04f7c7b3-2959-4e73-b025-c659677e26b0    I    -1  14585244   14625437
196ac1ea-b1e3-4617-9aa6-e39bde10524b    I    -1  14620212   14620633


ref:

             Chr    Strd      start         end
Gene name               
2L52.1        II       1        1848        4717
2RSSE.1       II       1    15268212    15275689
4R79.2        IV      -1    17480396    17483332
lev-11         I      -1    14621173    14631254
```

for every row in data, I'm trying to verify some conditions (by comparing with ref) and return the index of ref when all the conditions are meet:

- Values in `['Chr']` and `['Strd']` must be the same in both data and ref
- `data['start'] >= ref['start']`
- `data['end'] =< ref['end']`

I tried this piece of code but it returns an error:

```
def func(x):
    m = np.logical_and.reduce((np.equal(x[:2].values, refgenes.iloc[:,:2].values), np.greater_equal(x[2], refgenes.iloc[:,2]), np.less_equal(x[3], refgenes.iloc[:,3]))).all(axis=1)
    return refgenes.index[m] if m.any() else None

out = data.apply(func, axis=1)

# >>> ValueError: ('could not broadcast input array from shape (20222,2) into shape (20222)', 'occurred at index 04f7c7b3-2959-4e73-b025-c659677e26b0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom function using Pandas indexing and Boolean masks. This is nothing more than a manual loop, but is adaptable to any number of conditions.

I have modified your data to get interesting results. Also note the output is a list, i.e. if more than one index is in-scope, it will be included in the list.

```
def get_gene(row):
    m1 = (ref['start'] <= row['start']) & (ref['end'] >= row['end'])
    m2 = (ref['Chr'] == row['Chr']) & (ref['Strd'] == row['Strd'])
    return ref[m1 & m2].index.tolist()

data['gene'] = data.apply(get_gene, axis=1)

print(data)

                                     Chr  Strd     start       end      gene
04f7c7b3-2959-4e73-b025-c659677e26b0   I    -1  14621175  14631250  [lev-11]
196ac1ea-b1e3-4617-9aa6-e39bde10524b  II     1      1900      4700  [2L52.1]
```

If there is guaranteed to be one match, you can index the first value:

```
return ref[m1 & m2].index[0]
```

If your guarantee is only that there will be at most one value, you can avoid indexing errors by using `next` with a default value:

```
return next(iter(ref[m1 & m2].index), None)
```

**Setup**

```
print(data)

                                     Chr  Strd     start       end
04f7c7b3-2959-4e73-b025-c659677e26b0   I    -1  14621175  14631250
196ac1ea-b1e3-4617-9aa6-e39bde10524b  II     1      1900      4700

print(ref)

        Chr  Strd     start       end
2L52.1   II     1      1848      4717
2RSSE.1  II     1  15268212  15275689
4R79.2   IV    -1  17480396  17483332
lev-11    I    -1  14621173  14631254
```

Comment: Seems great but it returns the following error `IndexingError: ('Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match', 'occurred at index 04f7c7b3-2959-4e73-b025-c659677e26b0')` . Also, if I'm sure there won't be more than one index returned, can I remove `tolist()` ? Thanks !

Comment: @FlorianBernard, Works for me. If you're sure there's only one, use `ref[m1 & m2].index[0]`. Be prepared for errors if there is no match. To handle that case, you might want `next(iter(ref[m1 & m2].index), None)`.

Comment: I don't know what was the error but now it works ! Thanks. I'm afraid it might be rather slow for big dataframes (that's why I was first looking into a vectorized solution) but at least this is a working solution, unlike my attempts.

Comment: @FlorianBernard, Unfortunately, `pd.DataFrame.apply` is *never* vectorised. You are still looping each row, even if your NumPy solution worked.

Comment: Maybe I could speed things up with np.apply_along_axis then ? Guess I'm stuck with looping over each rows anyway.